# Two Constructors with int and long params in same class

Tags: java, constructor

I want to test if I have two `constructors` one has `params` as `int` and other as `long`. Which one will executed when called?

I have tried:

```
public class OverloadingExample {
 public  OverloadingExample(int i, int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        System.out.println("Hello"+" "+(i+j));
}
 public  OverloadingExample(long i, long j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
    System.out.println("long"+(i+j));
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    OverloadingExample duplicacyInHashMap = new OverloadingExample(20, 30);
    System.out.println(duplicacyInHashMap);
}
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Hello 50
OverloadingExample@6d06d69c
```

I believe both constructors called because `params 20,30` are `int` as well as `long` type. So whats wrong with second constructor why it doesn't print "long 50".

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'll get rid of my earlier comment to avoid confusion. In any case, it isn't going to execute several methods/constructors when only one call is made, and it shouldn't. That's pretty much a recipe for disaster. More than one method should be executed only when more than one method is called. Both of the constructors you provided _could be called_, but only one **will** execute.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the constructor which accepts two `long` values to be called, you will need to explicitly pass in `long` variables:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OverloadingExample duplicacyInHashMap1 = new OverloadingExample(20, 30);

    OverloadingExample duplicacyInHashMap2 = new OverloadingExample(20L, 30L);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello 50
long50
```

**Update:**

What is more interesting is what happens when you pass in one `int` and one `long`:

```
OverloadingExample duplicacyInHashMap3 = new OverloadingExample(20L, 30);
```

In this case, we get the output `long50`, meaning that the JVM treats the value `30` as a `long`.  Note that it would not be possible for `20L` to be treated as an `int` because it is explicitly a `long` value (ending in `L`) and casting might result in loss of precision.

Comment: Ok, long constructor was never executed then why it didn't execute int constructor twice, instead of giving gibberish in second line of output

Comment: You only made one call to the constructor in your original code.  The "gibberish" is there because you are trying to print an `OverloadingExample` object, and you never overrode its `toString()` method.

Comment: After trying `System.out.println(duplicacyInHashMap.toString())` it is still same output `Hello 50
OverloadingExample@6d06d69c`

Comment: When you pass an object into `System.out.println()`, the JVM will automatically call toString(). `System.out.println(duplicacyInHashMap.toString())` is the same as `System.out.println(duplicacyInHashMap)`.

Comment: In your previous comment you suggested to use `.toString`. So, whats the correct way to do it?

Comment: You need to define (override, to be exact) the `toString()` method inside your `OverloadingExample` class.  Inside this method you can print whatever you wish should be the string representation.  To put it plainly, _you_ need to tell Java how you want the class printed.  Have you asked yourself precisely _what_ you even expect to be printed out right now?  How can Java know this without you telling it?

Answer (score 1):

Both constructors are applicable. If you remove the 1st one, the 2nd one will be used - we can pass an `int` argument to a `long` parameter.

Since both are applicable, the compiler chooses the most specific one. The `(int)` version is more specific than the `(long)` version, because `int` is a subtype of `long`.

This is indeed a little confusing; avoid it if you can.

Comment: `int` is a subtype of `long`?

Comment: @PaulBoddington - yes, very weird - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.1

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that.